# What exactly is randomized with ASLR in MacOS X and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, security, osx-lion, ios6

Does anybody have a link to a documentation what exactly is randomized in what cases for latest Mac OS (10.7) and iOS (6.0)?

I mean. I want to see a list (something like)

- Code segment (in a case A,B,C)
- Stack (always)
- Heap
- Data segment (never)

Preferably with how many bits of randomization each thing has.

All I can find is something like: "MacOS Lion implements full ASLR" and in other places "full ASLR is implemented different ways for different operation systems", which is obviously not very informative.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The list you are looking for can easily be generated by you, as follows:

```
int global_j = 0;

void main ()
{

    char *h = malloc(10);
    int j = 0;

    printf ("Globals are : %p, text is %p, stack is %p, heap is %p\n",
        &global_j, main, &j, h);

}
```

On mountain lion, this yields:

```
bash-3.2# ./a
Globals are : 0x10fa55020, text is 0x10fa54eb0, stack is 0x7fff501ab864, heap is 0x7f9b294000e0
bash-3.2# ./a
Globals are : 0x106bbe020, text is 0x106bbdeb0, stack is 0x7fff59042864, heap is 0x7f9752c000e0
bash-3.2# ./a
Globals are : 0x108673020, text is 0x108672eb0, stack is 0x7fff5758d864, heap is 0x7fecc34000e0
bash-3.2# ./a
Globals are : 0x1059d2020, text is 0x1059d1eb0, stack is 0x7fff5a22e864, heap is 0x7f8f81c000e0
```

Showing ample randomization on all (note that due to alignment restrictions the offset within the page doesn't get randomized, but you still get some 16-20-bit randomization, as implied by the 4-5 hex digits which change).

- Kernel: As of Mountain Lion and iOS6, the kernel is randomized by "sliding" it with a value of vm_kernel_slide, on load. Not all vm pages are slid in this way, but for the most part this works by storing some constant value (which is also readable by System call #439, kas_info, on ML but not on iOS:  Apple is struggling hard to keep the randomization value secret, and not leak it when reporting kernel addresses, so jailbreakers won't figure out where they can jump to/overwrite - which works for them most of the time)

Hope this helps,

TG

Comment: Few years later, Apple introduced System Integrity Protection feature. Systems after ElCapitan disable `kas_info` syscall, so don't depend on it. (I think disabling `kas_info` on ElCapitan was buggy, but it surely is disabled on Sierra, until you disable SIP; then you can use `kas_info`)

Answer (score 8):

**No PIE:**

Executable - Fixed

Data - Fixed

Heap - Randomized per execution

Stack - Fixed

Libraries - Randomized per device boot

Linker - Fixed

**With PIE:**

Executable - Randomized per execution

Data - Randomized per execution

Heap - Randomized per execution(more entropy)

Stack - Randomized per execution

Libraries - Randomized per device boot

Linker - Randomized per execution

Comment: I did a quick test on Monterey (macOS 12.1, `x86_64`) and it looked like small allocations via `malloc` were not randomized under `-fno-pie`. However, very large allocations (100MB+) did seem to be randomized.